# how to find divisors of a given number in python and append them to a list?

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm trying to find all divisors of a given number and append them to a list. However, when I try to append them, the program also appends the number it iterates through and the proper divisors are appended in the end of the list. How can I avoid appending incorrect divisors? my code and output is below:

```
n=12
lis=[]
for i in range(2, (n+1) ):
    for j in range(1,i):
        if i % j == 0:
            lis.append(j)
```

my output was: [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]

How can I get the following output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]

Comment: You are simply trying to find a divisors right? The code you have now is not finding the divisor of n but rather the divisors all numbers [2,n+1) comparative to each [1,i). 

So you are doing the same comparisons multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

This code is seriously flawed. `i % j` is really an unrelated check. If I try to create an answer close to yours, this will work:

```
n=12
lis=[1]
for i in range(2, (n) ):
    for j in range(1,i):
        if i * j == n:
            lis.append(i)
            lis.append(j)
```

Which you can then sort afterward. But this inner loop is bad: it tells you no more information than `n % i == 0` would and it does so much more slowly. A better answer which does not involve nesting loops would be:

```
n=12
lis=[1]
for i in range(2, n):
    if n % i == 0:
        lis.append(i)
```

Of course, this can be improved further: notice that we do not need to check any higher than half of `n` because no value greater than `n / 2` will divide `n` evenly. In the best case, if you append `i` and `n // i` at the same time, you only have to check `i` from 2 to the square root of n.

Comment: i % j is not unrelated check. The operator % checks the modulus of the division: https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_oper_mod

Comment: @NataliaResende How does `i % j == 0` tell you if either of those values is a divisor of `n`?

Comment: if the product of i % j is equal to 0  that means that the number stored in j is a divisor of the given number : 12/6=2 > modulus 0 so 6 is a divisor but 12/5 = 2 modulus 2 then 5 is not a divisor then it should not be appended to the list

Answer (score 0):

I've found the below solution

```
def sumPdivisors():
    n=int(input('Enter a number to find the sum of its divisors: '))
    lis=[]
    for i in range(2, (n+1) ):
        pass
    for j in range(1,i):
        if i % j == 0:
            lis.append(j)

    print("the sum of the proper divisors of {} if {}". 
format(n,sum(lis)))    
          
sumPdivisors()
```

Comment: That's exactly the same answer as posted by @Kraigolas. Your do-nothing loop at the top simply sets `i` equal to `n` in the least efficient manner conceivable.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands you are comparing the following

```
2%1
3%1
3%2
4%1
4%2
4%3
5%1
5%2
5%3
5%4
6%1
6%2
6%3
6%4
6%5
7%1
7%2
7%3
7%4
7%5
7%6
8%1
8%2
8%3
8%4
8%5
8%6
8%7
9%1
9%2
9%3
9%4
9%5
9%6
9%7
9%8
10%1
10%2
10%3
10%4
10%5
10%6
10%7
10%8
10%9
11%1
11%2
11%3
11%4
11%5
11%6
11%7
11%8
11%9
11%10
12%1
12%2
12%3
12%4
12%5
12%6
12%7
12%8
12%9
12%10
12%11
```

You can see that your script is comparing numbers that have nothing to do with 12.

Edit:

I just added print statements to your code.

```py
n=12
lis=[]
for i in range(2, (n+1) ):
    for j in range(1,i):
        print("{}%{}".format(i,j))
        if i % j == 0:
            lis.append(j)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to programming. Not very experienced but it is exactly what the program does